# Reading a python UUID byte string in C++?

Tags: c++, python, byte, uuid

I have a string of 16 bytes in python created from the uuid.bytes method, something like:
    'I\x9e|T\r\xad@\x80\x986m\x00\x1c\x07z0'
for example, that I am passing to a C++ file.

Is there a way for me to read that from the C++ side and reconstruct the UUID? I was going to read it into a 16-char array since a char = 1 byte, but not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (untested)

```
char to_hex(int x)
{
  return x < 10 ? x + '0' : (x - 10) + 'A';
}

char bytes[16];
...
std::string uuid;
for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i)
{
  uuid += to_hex((bytes[i] >> 4) & 0x0F);
  uuid += to_hex(bytes[i] & 0x0F);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use:

```
UUID.hex
```

unless you need it in a binary representation.  No use converting back and forth.

Comment: Unfortunately, do need it in a binary representation.